# How do I give myself a broken Elytra [1.14]

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is there any way to get a broken elytra in creative mode? I saw a question like this 2 years ago, but I have tried it now, and it did not work.

Comment: That old question was for MCPE, that's why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

This command will give you an elytra with 0 durability.

```
/give @s minecraft:elytra{Damage:432}
```